# Error: ';' expected - Not sure how to debug or what's causing the error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, character-encoding

I've been working on another small project and have encountered a rather annoying bug that I can't seem to fix. Below is a method that takes a string and an integer and then returns character values increased by the integer parameter. I wanted to check for blank spaces " " and made a simple IF statement to check if the decimal value of the character equals 32 then to simply print the space and continue the loop. But when I go to compile it, Java tells me there's an error with my If statement line "error: ';' expected"

```
public static void getCodedMsg(String msg, int code){

    int temp;
    char codedMsg;

    for(int i = 0; i<= msg.length()-1; i++){

        temp = msg.charAt(i);

        If(temp == 32){
            System.out.print(temp);
            continue;
        }   

        temp = temp + code;
        codedMsg = (char)temp;
        System.out.print(temp);

    }

}
```

Can some kind soul let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? I'm not sure I'm even going about this the correct way. Maybe I should be using character arrays instead? Essentially, I need to take a string, add an integer to every character within the string to scramble it, and then print that result..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because in java [`if-statements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), the `if` isn't capitalized. So change:

```
If(temp == 32){
```

to:

```
if(temp == 32) {
```

Comment: Moral of the story: upper-case and lower-case **matter** in Java!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax incorrect, Fix:

```
if (temp == 32) {
    System.out.print(temp);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes (on both answers)? This is correct.

Comment: Maybe point out exactly what was wrong? It is very easy to look at this answer and miss the very subtle difference between what the OP posted.  A simple "If should be all lowecase" would be a bit clearer.

Comment: Also should maybe just be voted to be closed for such a simple typo.  Is this question really going to help in the Future?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I believe thats right, but in that case question needs to be downvoted not the answer

Comment: @AmanChhabra Personally I don't think anything needs downvoting - sorry to give you that impression